# As an app publisher, is there any way to monitor which incompatible devices visited the download page?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

I am dealing with an audience with a low tech knowledge and am having feedbacks from users who don't find the app or can't download it on Google Play and the App Store. I would thereby like to **monitor which devices visited the download page** but couldn't install the app because their device isn't compatible. On Google Analytics, it is possible to track the devices who visited specific URLs. I'm thereby wondering if this same tracking is possible for an app's download page.

I found this for the Play Store, but it doesn't really answer the question since I haven't defined exclusion rules :
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455?hl=en

Comment: i think this is interesting, but i doubt this would be possible, i'm not sure if either of the stores would provide you with this info, and i'm not entirely sure if Google Analytics would help either, isn't google analytics only limited to having the app actually installed ?